# have a pre-loaded directory when using tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory()

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following code:

imports:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, askdirectory
```

main:

```
master = Tk()
Label(master, text="Output dir").grid(row=1, column=0 ,sticky=W)
with open('{}\\resources\\last_saved_dir.config'.format(path_of_main_project), 'r') as saved_dir:
    last_dir = saved_dir.read().replace('\n', '')
entry_dir=Entry(master, text=last_dir, width=50)
entry_dir.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W, padx=5)
Button(master, text="Browse...", width=10, command=lambda:get_ouput_directory(entry_dir)).grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=W)

# The following part is after directory is chosen, runs the rest of the program. 
# Not important for my question, just showing that I run and close my loop.

Button(master, text="Ok",     command=run_and_close, width=10).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=E, padx=5)
Button(master, text="Cancel", command=close, width=10).grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W)

master.bind('<Return>', run_and_close)
master.bind('<Escape>', close)

mainloop()
```

This creates a gui window that prompts the user to enter a directory, with the text **Output dir** and then an open entry window with a **Browse** button to load the directory

The following is `get_ouput_directory()` function:

```
def get_ouput_directory(directory_entry):
    dir_name = askdirectory(title = "SiteConverter output directory")
    directory_entry.delete(0,END)
    directory_entry.insert(0,dir_name)
    with open('{}\\resources\\last_saved_dir.config'.format(path_of_main_project), 'w') as saved_dir:
        saved_dir.write(dir_name)
```

The idea is:

1. First time user runs this, the entry window is empty and the user would browse for a directory, which is then saved inside a certain folder in a file called `last_saved_dir.config`
2. Second time user runs the program, the program would read that file and load the directory inside the window so the user doesn't have to manually input it every time if the directory is unchanged.

Note that the program doesn't start reading the file from second run, it would always read, but the first time would either be an unwanted directory or blank if the user is running it for the first time. However every time I run the script the entry window is blank even though the last directory is saved inside `last_saved_dir.config`. When I add `print(last_dir)` just before `entry_dir=Entry(master, text=last_dir, width=50)` the last directory is read correctly and the the type is `<class 'str'>` which should be good for `text= ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what the `text=` option of an Entry does, since it isn't mentioned [in](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112032001/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) [any](https://web.archive.org/web/20190530085656/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry.html) [reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_entry.htm). To put text in an entry use the `.insert()` method:

```
entry_dir.insert(END, last_dir)
```

Then, to always open the `askdirectory` window with the folder currently in the Entry, use

```
dir_name = askdirectory(title = "SiteConverter output directory", initialdir=directory_entry.get())
```

---

As per Bryan Oakley's [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51381932/have-a-pre-loaded-directory-when-using-tkinter-filedialog-askdirectory/51382287?noredirect=1#comment89736946_51382287), Tkinter accepts abbreviations of option names as long as they are unique. The Entry widget doesn't have a `text` option, but it does have a `textvariable` option so that's the one you set when you set `text=...`. That makes that if you were to use it, you shouldn't give it a string object but a [StingVar](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112025221/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) object. For this specific example you're good without it though.

Comment: `text` is just shorthand for `textvariable`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for the clarification! That is a little confusing though since `text` and `textvariable` for a Label are completely different. Oh well..

Comment: Yes, it can be mildly confusing, which is why it's generally not a good idea to use abbreviations. The underlying tcl/tk interpreter accepts any unique prefix for all options, so it's not just that `text` is special. This is simply how tk works under the hood.

Comment: Aha, I never knew!