# Entry text option: curious behavior

Tags: python, tkinter

Consider the following code:

```
import  tkinter as tk

FONT="Arial 20 bold"

app = tk.Tk()

tk.Entry(app,text="hi", font=FONT).pack()
tk.Entry(app,text="hi", font=FONT).pack()

app.mainloop()
```

[image: animated view]

This animation shows, that the text contents are connected one to the other: change in one entry automatically updates the other one. Notice that text options are not bounded to any stringVar object but to a **string literal**.

Curiously, if text options are initialized to **distinct** litteral string, for instance "hi and Hi", entry contents become unrelated.

Is this the expected behavior?

#### [edit]: Addition to the description of this strange behavior:

With three entries, the two that have the same text are also linked:

```
import  tkinter as tk

FONT="Arial 20 bold"

app = tk.Tk()

tk.Entry(app, text="hi", font=FONT).pack()
tk.Entry(app, text="there", font=FONT).pack()
tk.Entry(app, text="hi", font=FONT).pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Even if these entries are assigned to distinct variables:

```
import  tkinter as tk

FONT="Arial 20 bold"

app = tk.Tk()

a = tk.Entry(app, text="hi", font=FONT).pack()
b = tk.Entry(app, text="there", font=FONT).pack()
c = tk.Entry(app, text="hi", font=FONT).pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is indeed very strange - at the very least, it violates the principle of least surprise - I added two related cases with three entries, two of which having the same definition.

Comment: Yes, very strange. Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies with the `text` parameter actually. By passing `text` you are creating a `textvariable` of the `Entry` widget:

```
import tkinter as tk

FONT="Arial 20 bold"

app = tk.Tk()

a = tk.Entry(app, text="hi", font=FONT)
b = tk.Entry(app, text="there", font=FONT)
c = tk.Entry(app, text="hi", font=FONT)

for i in (a,b,c):
    i.pack()
    print (i["textvariable"])

app.mainloop()
```

To fix this problem - simply don't pass `text` as a parameter. I don't think you need it anyways.

Comment: Indeed, [effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) doesn't document the text option (however, an example is provided but the code seems to be incomplete or damaged). The same for Shipman'docs (no link provided because website is down): no reference to a text option.

Comment: I don't think it was intended to pass `text` as a parameter at all - that's why it was not documented. It should have raised an error instead. But what I assume is when people pass `text` in a entry widget, they wanted to set some default text, which should have been done via `entry.insert` method.

Comment: In fact, [Entry source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L3022) doesn't record a valid *text* name option.

Comment: It was inherited from `Widget`. Perhaps it was there instead? I am not able to view the source files right now.

Comment: I don't have an official source for this, but [Bryan Oakley once commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51381932/have-a-pre-loaded-directory-when-using-tkinter-filedialog-askdirectory/51382287#comment89738698_51382287) that "the underlying tcl/tk interpreter accepts any unique prefix for all options". That means that, since an Entry widget doesn't have a `text` option, it will be seen as an abbreviation for `textvariable`.

Comment: Good research @HenryYik