# tkinter diferent entries are taking same value

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

while doing some practice with tkinter i have faced this problem. I want to set up 4 diferents entries where the user has to type 4 diferent values. The problem is that when  i try it, i type a value in any entry and the value automaticaly goes to all the entries.

i.e: I type a 4 in any of the four entries, and all entries get a 4.
[(see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mal3L.jpg)

This is the code so far:

```
from tkinter import *


class Application(Frame):
    def Check(self):
        print("check result")

    def createWidgets(self):

        self.tile1.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=20, pady=10)
        self.tile2.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=20, pady=10)
        self.tile3.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=20, pady=10)
        self.tile4.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=20, pady=10)
        self.QUIT.pack({"side": "left", "ipadx": 20, "padx": 10, "pady": 20})
        self.check.pack({"side": "left", "ipadx": 20, "padx": 10, "pady": 20})
    '''
    def callback(self,tile1,tile2,tile3,tile4):
        self.tile1.set(self.tile1.get()[:1])
        self.tile2.set(self.tile2.get()[:1])
        self.tile3.set(self.tile3.get()[:1])
        self.tile4.set(self.tile4.get()[:1])
    '''
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.num1 = int(0)
        self.num2 = int(0)
        self.num3 = int(0)
        self.num4 = int(0)

        self.tile1 = Entry(master=root, textvariable=self.num1, width=1)
        self.tile2 = Entry(master=root, textvariable=self.num2, width=1)
        self.tile3 = Entry(master=root, textvariable=self.num3, width=1)
        self.tile4 = Entry(master=root, textvariable=self.num4, width=1)

        self.QUIT = Button(self)
        self.QUIT["text"] = "QUIT"
        self.QUIT["fg"] = "red"
        self.QUIT["command"] = self.quit

        self.check = Button(self)
        self.check["text"] = "Check",
        self.check["command"] = self.Check

        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()


root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.master.title("Insertar titol")
app.master.maxsize(500, 500)
app.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

Comment: @gboffi: it's not that small integers are cached. It's simply that it uses an integer when it needs to be using one of the special tkinter variables.

Comment: @BryanOakley oops, I was_almost_ right.  It looks like you don't want to close this question, correct?

Comment: @gboffi: I couldn't find a good duplicate. I'm pretty sure there is one, but it took me less time to answer than it would have taken to find a proper duplicate. The one you link to doesn't seem close enough to be a good duplicate since the root of the problem is using an `int` for the `textvariable`.

Comment: I cleaned up too much of my prev comments, the question I had linked is [Entry text option: curious behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56440526/entry-text-option-curious-behavior)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I knew someone must have asked this before but i struggled choosing a precise title which is why i think i did not find the answer in a previous question. Anyways, Thanks alot guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the same value and the wrong type of value for the `textvariable` attribute. The `textvariable` attribute requires an instance of one of the tkinter variables such as `StringVar` or `IntVar`.

In essence, you are telling each `Entry` widget to save its data in a variable named `0` (zero). Since every widget uses the same variable name, the widgets are intrinsically linked so that a change in one affects them all.

The solution is to use distinct instances of `StringVar` or `IntVar` for each widget, instead of a literal zero.